# Allow the creation of omnibus answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers

When a question gets many good answers, it should be possible to write one that takes good parts from each answer and combines them to make it a quick solution for future readers.

For example I got this idea from this question: [How to split() a string to an array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911413/javascript-split-string-to-array-of-integers)

Comment: Why do we need a new feature for that?

Comment: What the hell is that shitshow of a question? It's a combination of _"how to loop over an array"_ and _"how to convert numbers-in-strings to numbers"_, both of which have been asked separately thousands of times already. Yet we have people dumping answers like it's a codegolf, and upvotes flowing like it's a dank meme?

Comment: Yeah, this is the kind of content that obviously belongs in Documentation. */ducks*

Comment: @CodeCaster Try answering a JS question as the first person. You'll nearly feel guilty because of all the upvotes you'll get. The JS tag is the wild wild west.

Comment: @Shog status-completed :D

Comment: I love it when folks request features that've existed since day one...

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a missing feature request in there - and that is that the selection process and the merging is an automatic thing rather than copy-pasting the content manually ;)

Comment: Come on look at your nerves :D If I don't try to improve or think about stackoverflow I'll miss one day the chance to create something great. be more loyal please. ;) Cheers.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili well you should try to improve or think about Stack. You should also consider how people NOW would do what you think should be done.... As Shog points out, what you want already exists... So this isn't "improving" the site

Comment: I see but I could not find it, because stack search engine needs improvements ;))

Comment: but anyway downvoting 11 times looks foolish not clever

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This already exists; just write that answer. Be sure to give credit to the answers you're drawing on for inspiration. [Here's an example](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-to-store-fresh-herbs/15654#15654)

Comment: (and make it a community wiki)